Build make target when directory structure changes
I have a script dir.ts that is part of my project website. It generates a JSON file with git repo tree structure, but it takes few seconds to run. Is there a way to check if the directory tree changes? I'm fine in generating a file that is ignored by the repo. I already do this to trigger the build when version changes.
I need to execute this code:
TS_NODE=./docs/node_modules/.bin/ts-node
ROOT=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`

dir:
    $(TS_NODE) ./docs/dir.ts $(ROOT) > ./docs/dir.json

This is similar to Build make target if contents of directory have changed

I figure out how to do this, the idea is to create a file name .tree in the root directory that will contain the output of git ls-files. And you update the file only when tree structure changes. You can do this with cmp command that compare two files (I only need this to speed up local development, so I don't need this file in the repository).
this is tree script which update the tree structure:
#!/bin/bash

TEMP_FILE=$(mktemp)
cd `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
git ls-files | sort > "$TEMP_FILE"

if [ ! -f .tree ]; then
  mv "$TEMP_FILE" .tree
else
  if ! cmp -s .tree "$TEMP_FILE"; then
    mv "$TEMP_FILE" .tree
  else
    rm "$TEMP_FILE"
  fi
fi

Then this is the content of the Makefile:
TS_NODE=./docs/node_modules/.bin/ts-node
ROOT=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`

.PHONY: update-tree

ALL: update-tree docs/dir.json

update-tree:
    @./scripts/tree

docs/dir.json: .tree ./docs/dir.ts
    $(TS_NODE) ./docs/dir.ts $(ROOT) > ./docs/dir.json


I don't see how this will work.  The target .tree doesn't depend on anything, so as long as the ./scripts/tree command is run one time (creating .tree) it will never run again so it will never notice that something changed.  You need to declare the .tree target as .PHONY.  Also you don't need something as complex as git diff --no-index, you can just use cmp.  And finally you probably want to sort the generated file to avoid spurious differences.

@MadScientist thanks for your suggestion, I need to replace .tree target with .PHONY target so .tree file will trigger the update of dir.json.

I'm not sure what you mean by "replace .tree target with .PHONY target".  .PHONY doesn't create a target.  It modifies the behavior of a target you created separately.  So, "replace" is not the right word.

@MadScientist by target I mean the thing before the colon. If I would just add .tree to .PHONY it will not work as expected. See my code.

I see no reason why it wouldn't work as expected by just declaring .PHONY: .tree in the original makefile.  That would be "more correct" since in the modified makefile you're relying on the implicit ordering of prerequisites to ensure that .tree is updated first; if you ever try this makefile with -j parallelism it will not work correctly.  BTW, the force-run: target is useless here.

@MadScientist If you make .tree .PHONY it will no longer check the file named .tree, the .tree dependency will always trigger the run of dir.ts. And this is not just hypothetical, I tested this, and it doesn't work. If you think that my code is redundant. Test it for yourself.

Hm somehow I had thought that while .PHONY targets are always built, things depending on .PHONY targets are only built if the target was updated.  Well, you can use the FORCE trick as in: .tree: FORCE ; ... then FORCE:, then .PHONY: FORCE to move the phony declaration one level down.  This ensures that the .tree recipe is always run, but that targets that depend on .tree are only run if it's changed.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html#index-FORCE

@MadScientist this is what I used in my code, but instead of FORCE I have update-tree.

No, your version is different because there is no rule to build .tree as a target.  That means that make doesn't actually understand that it has to wait for the update-tree recipe to finish before it can run the recipe to build the json file: you have not declared a prerequisite relationship between them.  Your makefile happens to work, only because make happens to build these in the order you want.  But if, as I mentioned, you try running make -j it will break because without a prerequisite relationship make can run both recipes at the same time.

@MadScientist my code do works, update-tree is in ALL before docs/dir.json and .tree is a file

It works in the cases you have tested.  If that's good enough (and maybe it is for your use case) that's fine.  But it's not completely correct in all situations, as I've explained above.

@MadScientist you can always add your own answer if you think that I'm wrong and can help other people.
